# collectionView doesn't scrollToItem - swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, collectionview, indexpath

I have a UICollectionview set inside a UIView in this way:

```
videoCollectionView.delegate = self
videoCollectionView.dataSource = self
    
self.playerView.insertSubview(videoCollectionView, belowSubview: additionalItemsView)
videoCollectionView.fillSuperview()
```

This is how the datasource and delegate methods are implemented

```
extension CardView : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    let numberOfURLS = cardModel?.urlStrings?.count
    return numberOfURLS!
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let videoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    videoCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.random()
    
    return videoCell
    
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height)
}
}
```

As you can see from the code above each cell is the size of the `collectionView.frame`
I want to have the collectionView cells displayed horizontally and to be able to scroll through them.

this is the code I implemented to scroll horizontally though the cells:

```
fileprivate func goToNextVideo(){
    
    counter = counter+1
    counter = min(cardModel!.urlStrings!.count-1, counter)
    
    videoCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: counter), at: .left, animated: true) 
}


fileprivate func goToPreviousVideo(){
    
    counter = counter - 1
    counter = max(0, counter)

    videoCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: counter), at: .left, animated: true)
}
```

I don't know for what reason, the collectionView doesn't scroll to the desired cell and I receive this warning in console:

```
Warning: Invalid IndexPath <NSIndexPath: 0xa5dbc31284d24cfa> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0} specified - will use a contentOffset of {0,0} as a fallback value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like

```
IndexPath(item: 0, section: counter)
```

is backward (twice). Try

```
IndexPath(item: counter, section: 0)
```

in both places.

Comment: It doesn't give me the warning as before but it doesn't scroll to the item of that index path yet , I also noticed that the contentSize of the collectionView is (355.0, 1667.0) which means it is developed vertically and not horizontally as I wanted to

Comment: Sure, I thought of that too, but that's a different matter. Saying whether this is a horizontally or vertically scrolling collection view is up to you. You didn't show _any_ of the code where you configure your `videoCollectionView`, so I have no reason to believe you're doing that correctly.

Comment: I solved it with adding a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout() and setting its scrollDirection property to horizontal

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what you mean by "custom"; UICollectionViewFlowLayout _has_ a `scrollDirection` property and you can just set it. You don't need to subclass for this purpose.